# ZF2: How to get error info from Zend\Db

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am connecting to MySQL through PDO with Zend\Db from ZF2.  How can I report the last `errorInfo()`?

Here's what I have:

```
    $sqlWriter = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
    $insert = $sqlWriter->insert('table_name')->columns(array_keys($data))->values($data);
    $stmt = $sqlWriter->prepareStatementForSqlObject($insert);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $object->id = $this->getAdapter()->driver->getLastGeneratedValue();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // 
        //  HOW CAN I display errorInfo() here? 
        //
        throw new Exception\Exception('Unable to insert record...');
    }
```

I have tried calling methods on the adapter, driver, statement, platform, result, etc...  But all to no avail...

EDIT: I found that I can get the info I am looking for by posting the following at the top of the catch block:

```
        $pdoException = $e->getPrevious();
        var_dump($pdoException);
```

I'll leave the question open however since it would be good to know how to execute PDO::errorInfo() directly.

Comment: Won't `$e->getMessage()` in the catch block give you the error?

Comment: In addition to what @TimFountain wrote above, wouldn't you be better catching the `\PDOException` if that's all you're interested in? -> http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: As you can see in the edit, I worked out how to access the PDO exception.  I have kept the question open though, since the answer would help me next time I want to access a different method of the PDO class.